# MySQL query throwing 1064 error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I have a huge data which is stored in mysql db. One of the columns in the database is a long string. One of the strings is "iEdge detected the 'warning' condition 'iedge it" which is stored in string_type. I have to query the database and find how many such strings are there.I am querying from my python program. When I do it using something like

```
  cur.execute("select count(*) from table1 as tmp where tmp.err_string='"+row[r]+"'")
```

row[r] contains "iEdge detected the 'warning' condition 'iedge it"

I am getting error 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax...). I think it is happening because of some quotes in the string. May I know how to fix this?

Comment: Include your exact query and maybe we can help you.

Comment: If you are looking to escape Single quotes, escape them by doubling them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
sql = "select count(*) from table1 as tmp where tmp.err_string=%s"
cursor.execute(sql, [row[r]])
```

Let the MySQL Python library worry about escaping special characters and how to quote your string.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798969/python-mysql-escape-special-characters) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. A small change, in cursor.execute(), the second argument should be an iterable object. So I changed it to cursor.execute(sql,[row[r]])