# Make XML code from request data and inserting to database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I am receiving data into an REST API, and I want to insert it as XML code into a database. When I later read the record from the database, I expect well-formed XML code.

```
data=str(request.data)
cur=mydb.cursor()
currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
val=data.replace("'","''")
cur.execute("insert into MyXMLApi(dateofInsertion,xmlData) values('%s','%s')"%(str(currentDT),val))
mydb.commit()
```

This is what I expect to see in the database:

```
"<note>
Don't forget me this weekend!
</note>"
```

However, this is what I actually get:

```
'b"<note>
Don''t forget me this weekend!
</note>"'
```

So I have three issues here.

1. I have to deal with single quotes in the XML code.
2. It should be stored as proper XML code.
3. When I read from the database, I can't get the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.data` is a bytestring in Flask. (See property `data` and `get_data()` in the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request).) But you want to save it as non-byte, just plain string to your database. Converting with `str()` is not the way to do it.

Assuming you want a UTF-8 string, replace your first line with

```py
data=request.data.decode('UTF-8')
```

Then you will be able to save it to your database.

About the single quotes, I don't think you should escape them yourself. Use [parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798969/python-mysql-escape-special-characters), and the library will do it for you.

(By the way, this sounds like a very strange use-case. Why not store `data` in your table as field `note`?)